# SQLAlchemy with gevent and mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, gunicorn, gevent

I couldn't find any "best-practice" regarding this issue.

What's the best approach using SQLAlchemy in a concurrent gevent environment?

I use gunicorn (with -k gevent flag) running a flask app.
This is the code for initializing the DB engine once:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
orm_engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://user:pass@127.0.0.1/mydb',
                           pool_size=10, strategy='threadlocal')
SessionFactory = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=orm_engine))
```

And this is the code per request:

```
log.info("Entering")
session = SessionFactory()
my_obj = session.query(MyObj).get(request['obj_id'])
my_obj.some_property += 1
session.add(my_obj)
session.commit()
session.close()
log.info("Exiting")
```

Even when running tens of concurent requests, the printed logs show always "Entering, Exiting, Entering, Exiting...". Never "Entering, Entering, Exiting, Exiting". Means that the gevent threads per request are blocked on I/O waiting for the query to return from the DB, but not switching to other waiting gthreads.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to either use a pure python driver (e.g. pymysql) or use [greenify](https://github.com/douban/greenify) to patch a C-based driver (e.g. mysqldb).

Comment: Thanks.
I tried Pymysql, but it still didn't work concurrently. Anything special should be done to make it work with gevent?

Comment: Nope, `monkey.patch_all()` patches python sockets so it should just work. Are you sure the concurrency is not working? How are you testing the concurrent requests?

Comment: My bad. After creating an external tester, I found it to be working well with the pymysql driver. Thanks!
Attaching here the code for the performance test for anyone who would like to observe it: https://gitlab.com/edibusl/flask_mysql_gevent/tree/master/

Comment: @univerio, does it work with `mysql` driver?